# add branch for review

Tags: git, github, git-branch, gerrit

I am new to Gerrit,

What I did:

```
// cloned repo
git clone repo.git

// created branch
git checkout -b "test"

// made some changes
created textfile1.txt

// added to stage
git add .

// commited
git commit -m "adding new file"

// pushed to gerrit
git push origin test
```

Now, my test branch pushed to gerrit, how do I add it to code review?

I am just reading documentation and it seems like in order to add it to code review, you are supposed to run the following command:

```
git push origin:HEAD/refs/for/master
```

Does it mean I had to do all my development on HEAD/refs/for/master branch?

What is the fix now?

Comment: That's `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`, not `git push origin:HEAD/refs/for/master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your local branch where you make your commits doesn't matter. It's your personal workspace and you can name your branches whatever you like.

Gerrit isn't used to review *branches*, you review *commits*. If you push a branch with more than one new commit (not the case in your example) you'll get multiple changes in Gerrit.

Yes, `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` is a common idiom for pushing changes for review to Gerrit. It means "push all new commits from the current head for review with the master branch as their destination once they've been approved and you press Submit".

Perhaps the [documentation's quick introduction chapter](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html) would be helpful?